# connection verification failed for data source - Coldfusion Server Administration

Tags: coldfusion-10

I have just installed ColdFusion 10 and am trying to connect to MySql Server 5.1, but it is showing the error below:

> Connection verification failed for data source: cfartgallery2
>   java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer
>   JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket. Unknown host: MySQL Server The
>   root cause was that: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket. Unknown
>   host: MySQL Server

Comment: The error message says *SQL Server* JDBC driver, but the host name says *MySQL* ? Which dbms were you trying to connect to: MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Finally after 2 days I solved my own problem of getting the above error. It was due to a missing ODBC connector.

**Steps for resolving:**

1. First download and install the ODBC connector of respective version as of your MYSQL server version.
2. Rhen install vcredist_x64 it is required for sql connectivity.
3. Then install any SQL Server to create the database and start connecting to it with the datasource you have created in tour CF Administrator.

Hope you can solve your problem with my instructions , if not then please post your queries below.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Two questions though A) Is there a specific reason you must use ODBC? The standard method is using the built in JDBC drivers. Pure [Type 4 JDBC drivers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3639b1-7ffd.html) are generally preferred over ODBC. B) Are the instructions for SQL Server OR MySQL (the above mentions both)